Understanding C Runtime libraries in Windows vs. Linux and best practices on linking
Are these equivalent?



Windows
Linux




vcruntime[version].dll
-static-libgcc


msvcp[version].dll
-static-libstdc++



Moreover, is it true that if I am statically linking the C runtime in my top level project (a library), then I should statically link the C runtime in ALL the dependencies recursively (a huge wastage) and vice-versa i.e., if linking dynamically, then ALL dependencies must also be linked dynamically?
In a large project, I don't necessarily have control over how the dependencies are built. How do I even find out if C runtime has been statically or dynamically linked in the dependencies?
It doesn't end here. Lets say my top level library is A and it depends on B. Say I link C runtime statically in B. So B has a copy of C runtime in it. Now I also statically link the C runtime in A and further link A statically against B. Then, won't I end up with two copies of C runtime in A? One copy results from statically linking C runtime in A and another copy is because I statically linked A against B which itself has a copy of C runtime in it? Won't this create problems?

[MSVC only]: will complain if you mix object files built with /MT[d] and /MD[d] in the same target. See also /MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library) "...All modules passed to a given invocation of the linker must have been compiled with the same run-time library compiler option (/MD, /MT, /LD)...."

I am no expert, but in my general experience static linking is simpler to get working and  less trouble-prone in the long run. Dynamic of course allows sharing, but - as you're implying - version compatibility can become complicated. I worked in a system (under Windows) some time ago where 3rd party libraries often clashed trying to load different versions of the C runtime DLL. Maybe that's been fixed by now. But even if versions don't clash, you will be loading all, so no code sharing. We ended up using the statically linked versions of all but one just to get it running.

my assertion is exactly the opposite - that static linking will create problems as there will be multiple copies of C runtime in final library

Right. If you get it to compile statically, you are guaranteed it will work forever, not blow up because of a DLL version issue on a target machine down the line..  My context is libs where you have no control  over target machine configuration.

Library version mismatches can be lethal, especially in C++. Say the implementation details of std::string changed and a buffer is a different size or a book-keeping variable was added. The memory layout is different. Now one side passes a reference to a std::string to the other. This other side accesses a pointer that it expects at offset 12 and gets something completely different. Boom.

libgcc is the gcc runtime, not the C runtime. Likewise, vcruntime is the MSVC runtime, not the C runtime. The C runtime would usually be libc/glibc on Linux and crt/ucrt on Windows.

@Gene I would say dll or static lib is a tradeoff. Since static libs can be a big pain to work with too, specially in larger systems, mainly because of transitive dependencies. If you want to link with static libs that use other libs that use other libs... you'd better make sure they all are the same versions (or you get ODR violations at link time).  So no static libraries are not always more easy (dll's can actually provide better encapsulation/hide their internal implementation details, at the cost of more disk/memory space)

In most cases you do not need to split your project into many files (exe+libraries). Don't try to make it more complex than necessary.

On linux (gcc) static libraries don't link anything, static libraries are only a package of object files, you only link the dependencies when creating the executable or shared object, at that point you can choose to statically link the runtime (note that you shouldn't statically link the C runtime on linux unless you absolutely need to Why is statically linking glibc discouraged?)

MSVC is the compiler with the "all static dependencies must use the same Runtime" restriction.

In a large project, I don't necessarily have control over how the dependencies are built. How do I even find out if C runtime has been statically or dynamically linked in the dependencies?

MSVC produces a hard link time error (LNK2038) if you mix static libraries that link two different runtime versions, all static libraries within a single executable or dll need to use the same runtime.
Not sure how reliable is this but .lib files contain RuntimeLibrary= specifying the runtime library to use which you can search for if you opened it in notepad, this is for visual studio 2022

Lets say my top level library is A and it depends on B. Say I link C runtime statically in B. So B has a copy of C runtime in it. Now I also statically link the C runtime in A and further link A statically against B. Then, won't I end up with two copies of C runtime in A?

You only have 1 runtime per executable or dll, the linker sorts this out. every executable or dll can contain any number of static libraries, it is the linker job to remove duplicate symbols within a single executable or dll. (or error out if it finds a duplicate symbol that shouldn't have a duplicate)
Specifying that a static library links the runtime statically doesn't put the entire runtime into the library, only the needed parts are linked into the final executable by the linker, however this does affect the code generation of the library (for example some of the runtime code is inlined into the library), which is why you need to specify whether to link the runtime statically or dynamically when compiling a static library.

If you have 1 executable and 1 dll and both statically link the runtime then you have 2 versions of the runtime and you need to watch out for allocator boundaries (which can crash your application), so it is preferred to dynamically link the runtime if you use dlls, this way both the executable and the dll will use the same heap and global runtime state, etc...

Equivalence of Libraries:
WindowsLinuxvcruntime[version].dll and msvcp[version].dll are similar for Windows.
static-libgcc and static-libstdc++ are similar for Linux/Unix.
Static vs. Dynamic Linking:
Static linking embeds library code into your executable.
Dynamic linking loads library code at runtime.
Dependency Linking:
Generally, use consistent linking across your project and dependencies.
Exceptions might exist, but avoid mixing if possible.
Check build scripts or use tools like ldd or dumpbin to inspect linking methods in dependencies.
